# Wix Install to C:/Users/User/AppData

Tags: c#, wix

I'm trying to find a way to install a program to the AppData folder for each user on a computer.  We have a computer that a group remotes into and each uses the program on that computer.  Currently the application is installed normally in the program files.  The reason we need individual installations is that we've updated the application to use AppLife Updater, and if someone runs the program while someone else is also running it, and it needs an update, the update will fail.  So we'd like to have each user have their own installation that won't interfere with other users installations when updating.

I've found that you can install to LocalAppDataFolder instead of ProgramFilesFolder, but when you do that, you get several ICE errors (Specifically, ICE38 and ICE64).  I found a web article that showed a version of a Wix installer that installs to the LocalAppDataFolder, but it also has ICE38 and ICE64 errors.

[AppData Wix Installer code/article](https://delog.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/adding-lots-of-source-files-to-a-wix-installer-script/)

My question is, has anyone made a Wix installer before that installs to the AppData folder that does not have these issues?  Is there documentation on how to do this, other than the cited article?  I have read the Rob Mensching blog article
[How to create an uninstall shortcut (and pass all the ICE validation)](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/how-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the/).

[ICE64 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369011(v=vs.85).aspx)

[ICE38 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368961(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The actual problem seems to be that your update fails, but you haven't described that at all. (Restart Manager is a typical solution). So you've decided that the solution is to have a copy of the app in all those folders . You've asked a classic XY question http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thank you for the perspective, @PhilDW.  I will take a look at Restart Manager.